# How to recreate an oracle 9i database from backup files (ora files)

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, controlfile

I'm a developer so I'm a little lost in the DBA world.  Our systems guys have given me a backup of an Oracle 9i database.  I have installed oracle 9i on my pc and am now trying to 'import' the backup files so I have a normal database to work with.

The backup folder has on SNCF[SID].ora file and around 150 [SID]-[Date]-[counter]-[soemnumber].ora files.  The question is, how do I get this data into oracle so I can query it through sql?

I have gotten as far as creating a database which matches the SID of the backed up database.  Google tells me that I need to go into rman and run "database restore."  But how does it know where the backfiles are located?

Any ideas?  Thanks.

---

I...don't...know.  Seriously, the Oracle data we backed up is part of a very old application which is being phased out.  No one really owns the database, and we have no DBAs on hand...so it falls on me, the only developer.  I can try to get more details for you tomorrow.

In the mean time, the original database runs on a windows machine and is some version of 9i.  I installed Oracle 9i (9.2.0.1.0) on my Windows XP box (I installed this older version specifically so I could recreate the database from the backed up files).

The backup was done specifically so I could try to recreate it on my pc (so we wouldn't mess with production).  We only have one window of a few hours a week, so it is not easy to just redo the backup differently.

A DBA friend advised that we export the database rather than doing a full backup; however, the systems guys had a problem with the export so now I have this full backup.

As far as control files are concerned, it looks like there is an SNCF[SID].ORA file, about 2.2 megs, which is apparently the control file.  All other files (a little over 150) are around half a gig, also with ORA endings.  I'm guessing those are the actual data files.

I'll get the exact oracle and windows versions soon.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first things first. Exactly what version of Oracle was the backup taken from? 9i is a marketing label-- we need the full 4 digit version number (i.e. 9.2.0.4). Is your PC running exactly the same version of Oracle? Is your PC running exactly the same operating system?

How was the backup done? Are you looking at a consistent cold backup of a database?

Do you not have any control files (normally .ctl)?

SNCF[SID].ORA sounds like a parameter file, not a control file.  You would need a control file to be able to restore the database.

If the database is actually up and running somewhere, I'm going to wager that you'll go through far less pain and agony overall if you work on figuring out why using the export utility didn't work and fixing that problem than in trying to recover the database from a cold backup, particularly if there is any sort of confusion over how the backup was taken.

Comment: Unfortunately so.  We'll have to give it another try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.ora files??? That's usually the extension for a pfile (in 9i you would prefer having an spfile instead).

No idea about the dated/numbered files. Maybe they're alert logs? or are they exp dumps with a weird extension. or are they part of an rman backup?

You say "The backup was done specifically so I could try to recreate it on my pc", so why don't you have specific instructions to restore it?

Sorry I have more questions than answers here. But I suggest you get expert help from a real DBA.

Your systems guys are a good bet. ask them for help, they created this mess.